# How to setup web.config transformation for website projects?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, vs-web-site-project

I have a website project and would like to setup different web.config transformation files for it, but the option doesn't exist when I right-click on the web.config file. Is this option limited to web applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Web Deployment Project.

For the VS 2010 version, see:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=24509

Comment: Looks like this might be [supported](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10356428/612265) now.