# Web.config transformation with SlowCheetah and ASP.NET Web site project

Tags: asp.net, web-deployment-project, vs-web-site-project, xslt, slowcheetah

I'm trying to use SlowCheetah XML Transforms with an `ASP.NET Web site project` (not an ASP.NET Web Application Project) in Visual Studio 2010.

When I right click on the `Web.config` file in my ASP.NET Web site project, I don't see "`Add Transform`" item in the contextual menu.

(Note: it works well when a try with an ASP.NET Web Application Project).

- Is it possible to use SlowCheetah with an `ASP.NET Web site project` ?
  Or it's impossible "by design" because this kind of project has limitations ?

May be there is a workaround merging the "`*.targets`" files of the "[Web Deployment Project 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=19995)" and SlowCheetah...

Comment: Aren't web site projects extinct? ;)

Comment: Well, I like "compile-on-the-fly" functionality and the magic Profile class with ASP.NET Web Site Project ;-)

Comment: No website projects are not extinct.

Comment: Website projects *ought* to be extinct.

Comment: There is some good news for Website projects: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/06/plans-regarding-website-projects-and-web-deployment-projects.aspx

Comment: @SpaceBison website project is awesome, you are missing out

Comment: @Ubikuity here is the follow up post to the link you posted http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/11/20/new-web-publish-updates.aspx

Comment: FYI see my answer below regarding how to vote for this feature for those interested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SlowCheetah doesn't support website projects. What behavior were you envisioning here for website projects? For WAP projects they are kicked in during package/publish. For the Web deployment project suggestion I have created an issue to track that at https://github.com/sayedihashimi/slow-cheetah/issues/4, but I'm not sure how that would actually work. I'll have to think about that for a bit.

#### Update

Website project now has the same publishing support as Web application project, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/11/20/new-web-publish-updates.aspx, if you would like SlowCheetah to support transforming XML files please vote for it at: https://slowcheetah.uservoice.com/forums/185106-general/suggestions/3398137-support-for-website-project

Comment: Web Deployment Project allows replacements but not transformations of the Web.config (and I would like to avoid maintaining several *.config files). For the moment, I use XmlPreProcess http://xmlpreprocess.codeplex.com/ but I'm looking for an alternative.

Comment: Have you thought about using the TransformXml task from MSBuild? I have blogged about how to do this at http://sedodream.com/2010/11/18/XDTWebconfigTransformsInNonwebProjects.aspx.

Comment: No, I didn't know this possibility (I'm new to MSBuild stuff). Thank you for the information.