# Does web.config transformations works with Build\Release?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

To deploy a website on production or UAT server, I perform following steps.

1)Build my website in build\release mode.

2)Copy the files manually and paste it on the production server.

I want to apply web.config transformations when website is bulid in release mode. Is it possible?
or is there any other way to change the value of connection string automatically when website is deployed on server.

I am not using webpublish or web packages methods for deployment.

Comment: Is there a GOOD reason why you don't just publish your website? Copying the files manually isn't the right thing to do it. I guess that you develop the asp.net website using Visual Studio.

Comment: Also check out these questions, as they may provide usefull informations [How do I do Web.config Transformations with Visual Studio Website Projects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082126/how-do-i-do-web-config-transformations-with-visual-studio-website-projects), [How to setup web.config transformation for website projects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8765812/how-to-setup-web-config-transformation-for-website-projects)

Answer (score 0):

You can use web publish to file system which is exactly as copy paste. You can publish to a folder in your machine and copy to server from there. After you run the publish, the files can be also found in `obj\release\Package\PackageTmp`